# Is there a tag for long term outcomes?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've asked a question about education, and specifically its impact on adulthood and how a specific educational issue affects the long term outcome of a child's life in terms of success, happiness, etc.

Is there a tag that embodies this idea?  While it might seem like every child raising question could carry such a tag, the reality is that most questions on the site appear to be about solving near-term problems or issues.  Yes, these will affect the remainder of their life, but most questions aren't specifically asking for a solution that brings the best out of them as an adult, regardless of the near term effects.

If there isn't a tag, what would it be called?

I'm thinking largely in terms of questions such as, "Between options X and Y, which option will most positively impact my child's adulthood?"  Studies and research would be more relevant to such questions than some others, but experiential answers would still play an important role.

Comment: I can't think of a single word for success (financial, professional, popular, personal), happiness, etc. I don't *think* there is one. Maybe *achievements*?

Comment: We also get questions regarding the negative: "If I do *this*, will it harm my child in the long run?"

Comment: I've [asked my superiors](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53207/word-for-results-after-a-long-period-of-time)...

Comment: I don't know that this makes sense as a tag, though the concept of a word for it is intriguing.  You're not going to search for questions based on their having to do with long-term outcomes.

Comment: If this were a tag, I think I *would* browse it. Long term effects are generally what I'm interested in, over short term. But you're right, I wouldn't search it. I'd only browse if the convenience was already there.